# How do you make your MDI MFC app show one instance in the TaskBar?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mdi

I have an MDI app and when I click new document, it opens up a separate tab.  This creates another instance of the icon in the taskbar within Windows.  Is there any way I can change this behavior so that only one icon instance is shown the taskbar?

I know one way is to use SDI and use tabs for my views, but I want to keep it an MDI.  Is this even possible.

I'm trying to mimic the view of this particular application called 'Dameware NT Utilities':
http://www.dameware.com/v3-dameware/media/DameWare/DW%20NTU/Carousel/DRS-Primary-medium.png?width=490&height=276&ext=.png

Comment: I believe *every* top-level window gets a tab in the taskbar. The only way to avoid it is to make every window a child of the main window.

Comment: In my app I have one main frame and one child frame.  My views are all currently using the child frame, but the tabs still show in the taskbar.  Does that mean frame hierarchy is different from window hierarchy?  Do you know how I'd go about setting the child windows to be child windows of the main window?

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now. Obviously there are aspects of the MDI interface that I'm out of date with.

Comment: I'm happy to say that after much digging around, I finally found the solution. I'll post as the answer.  Thanks Mark for getting me thinking in the right path.  It was a matter of overriding the child window's (child frame) CanShowOnTaskBarTabs() methodl.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution after a day of digging around.  Gosh, that feels good to finally figure this out.  Anyway here is the solution.

I just had to override the childframe's `CanShowOnTaskBarTabs()` method to return FALSE.  Here's the class method:

first, in the childframe.h file, put the following code in the class declaration

```
public:
     virtual BOOL CanShowOnTaskBarTabs() override;
```

Then in your childframe.cpp file, put the following code at the very bottom:

```
BOOL CChildFrame::CanShowOnTaskBarTabs()
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Here's more information on the subject: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256255(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Doesn't show up in Class Wizard, but works nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

I have an easier solution. On the app class `InitInstance()` method, just call

```
EnableTaskbarInteraction(FALSE);
```

before the main frame has been created. Then you will get one view per application instance when mouse does fly hover on its Taskbar icon, instead of one per sub-winodow.