# Displaying MDI Application as a single ICON on the TaskBar (VC++/MFC)

Tags: windows, visual-c++, mfc, mdi, taskbar

I have created an MDI app based on the MFC DocView architecture in the latest version of  Visual-Studio, which is working well.
However, when the application is running, and its minimised icon is displayed on the desktop TaskBar, all the open documents are displayed along side one-another.  Is there a way I can get only the Document having the current Focus show on the minimised list.

(In case I am not explaining my problem properly, try opening Microsoft Word, and creating a few empty documents.  Now click on the minimised Word Icon on the taskbar and you see all open documents displayed alongside each other. This is exactly what I am trying to solve.  I only want one document to show up in this list.  Is there a way ?)

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Mine show the same for my MDI application and Word.

Comment: Have you tried to create the MFC project as multiple top level documents ? I guess this is what you looking for ...

Comment: WRT creating the project as a serious of Top Level Documents, it is too late to change the architecture of the project.  Much has been developed on top of that and it cannot be reversed at this late stage.  If I went back and started the project again, i would do it differently, as MDI is actually not necessary for this project. My Project Manager is an idiot and did not give me a proper spec at the start so I went with MDI as it sounded the most plausible.  However, If there's a way of simply showing the Application Icon as minimised, I would be grateful.   Many Thanks fro your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Hello those Who have read or are interested in a solution to this dilemma:

I found it at:

[How do you make your MDI MFC app show one instance in the TaskBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255935/how-do-you-make-your-mdi-mfc-app-show-one-instance-in-the-taskbar/55376904#55376904)

And it works.  best wishes all.