# How to avoid MFC application 's icon is stacked?

Tags: winapi, mfc

I have created a new project by copying an existing project. I want this newly created project to be recognized as another project. In the case of the registry, I was able to change some settings to make it recognized as another program. However, it is impossible to avoid the phenomenon of overlapping icons on the taskbar as if the same program was running. What value do I need to modify to be recognized as a different program?

Please give me piece of advices.

Comment: Maybe change the `AppTitle` string? The .exe name? Also take o look into the registry entry `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\AppName.exe]`, `FriendlyAppName` key. Related documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration?redirectedfrom=MSDN#applications

Comment: Don't manually modify the registry. Not only is that dangerous, it only works on your local computer. You need to change the code. Modify all places where the AppWizard inserted strings that are meant to be unique to your application. Make them unique to the application.

Comment: Perhaps is this you are searching for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60975488/383779

Comment: Also remember to check if InitInstance called SetRegistryKey and if so, adjust the key name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to recognize the uniqueness of MFC apps. Generally, when a project is created through the MFC wizard, a function called SetAppID is called in the class inheriting CWinAppEx to define the uniqueness of the app. If you give an appropriate eigenvalue to that part, it will be recognized as another program. Thanks to everyone who helped in the comments above.

Comment: _"eigenvalue"_ ? Are you shure this is the correct word?